# ZF2: How to catch exceptions thrown by a view helper automatically

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-view

I have a some view helpers throwing exceptions on error. That's ok for development, but for production I would like to configure `PhpRenderer` to catch and log the exception without braking the hole view file to render - simply return nothing.

The `PhpRenderer` has the method:

```
public function __call($method, $argv)
{
    if (!isset($this->__pluginCache[$method])) {
        $this->__pluginCache[$method] = $this->plugin($method);
    }
    if (is_callable($this->__pluginCache[$method])) {
        return call_user_func_array($this->__pluginCache[$method], $argv);
    }
    return $this->__pluginCache[$method];
}
```

Is it enough to overwrite this method?

How can I replace the `PhpRenderer` with my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by writing your own view strategy.

First, register your new strategy in the configuration.

```
return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyStrategy' => 'Application\ViewRenderer\StrategyFactory',
        )
        'view_manager' => array(
               'strategies' => array(
                   'MyStrategy'
                ), 
         ),
);
```

Then, create your own strategy

```
namespace Application\ViewRenderer;

use Zend\View\Strategy\PhpRendererStrategy;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

class StrategyFactory implements FactoryInterface
{


    public function createService (ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $renderer = new Renderer ();

        return new Strategy ($renderer);
    }
}
```

and renderer.

```
namespace Application\ViewRenderer;
use Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer;

class Renderer extends PhpRenderer
{
    public function render($nameOrModel, $values = null) {
            // this is just an example
            // the actual implementation will be very much like in PhpRenderer
        return 'x';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea that is it, thanks! The only method I have to overwrite is ``__call``